# remove quotes in JSON array. Controller or JS?

Tags: javascript, json, json.net

I have the following dataset:

```
Sampled Target    
54      100   
53      100  
9       25   
63      100
```

I am then concatenating these rows into comma separated result to produce a JSON using the following code in my MVC controller:

```
JArray secondChart = new JArray(new JObject(
                                           new JProperty("name", "sampled"),
                                           new JProperty("data", new JArray(string.Join(",", MyContext
                                                    .Select(p => p.SpecimenSampled))))
                                                    ),
                                                    new JObject(
                                           new JProperty("name", "remaining"),
                                           new JProperty("data", new JArray(string.Join(",", MyContext
                                                    .Select(p => (p.SpecimenTargets - p.SpecimenSampled)))))
```

It produces the following json:

```
[{
 "name": "sampled",
 "data": ["54,53,9,63"]
 },
 {
 "name": "remaining",
 "data": ["46,47,16,37"]
 }
 ]
```

While i would except:

```
[{
 "name": "sampled",
 "data": [54,53,9,63]
 },
 {
 "name": "remaining",
 "data": [46,47,16,37]
 }
 ]
```

In order to be consumed by my javascript and to display a chart.

I have tried to get rid of the double quote in the controller but didn't succeed because of the string.Join which merges all my rows into a comma separated string.
I also tried at the javascript level but failed as well.

Thanks for your solution either in the controller or the javascript.

Sylvain

Comment: You're passing a single string to the JArray constructor, how else should it behave?

Comment: Would it be possible to generate the expected JSON from the controller directly considering that I am concatenating rows into a comma separated result which can only be of String type...This is my problem

Comment: You just need to remove the `string.Join` call and everything will work as expected.

Comment: I have edited my question with the initial dataset. How would you concatenate the rows for each columns without using the `string.Join`?

Comment: Why do need to concatenate them at all?

Comment: How would you generate the expected JSON from the initial dataset using JSON.net?

Comment: `JArray.FromObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @aluan-haddad

I was mistakenly preprocessing the concatenation which would be taken care directly by JSON.net, so i just had to update my controller;

```
JArray secondChart = new JArray(new JObject(
                                           new JProperty("name", "sampled"),
                                           new JProperty("data", new JArray(MyContext
                                                    .Select(p => p.SpecimenSampled)))
                                                    ),
                                                    new JObject(
                                           new JProperty("name", "remaining"),
                                           new JProperty("data", new JArray(MyContext
                                                    .Select(p => (p.SpecimenTargets - p.SpecimenSampled))))
```